# Loading tab activities in background in android

Tags: android, multithreading, tabs

In my application, there is a tab in which 4 activities are included. When the tab is shown to the screen, one of the activities get loaded and shown to the user. When I press other tabs, the corresponding activities are loading. I want to load all activities in background when I load the first tab.Because I want to use some resources from other activities in my first tab activity. can anyone please help? this is the code of tab:

```
public class Tab extends TabActivity {

    private TabHost tabHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);


    tabHost = getTabHost();


    Intent s = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),s.class);
    Intent c = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),c.class);
        Intent nu = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),D.class);
        Intent l = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),l.class);     
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Lo").setIndicator("Lo",null).setContent(l));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Nu").setIndicator("Nu",null).setContent(nu));
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("ct").setIndicator("c",null).setContent(c));      

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("S").setIndicator("S",null).setContent(s));           
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
    }
```